# Tableau Trusted Authentication not working/no error

Tags: php, tableau-api

For our new reporting tool we are using Tableau, however we want our users to simply login our website in order to see the info.

On the server side of tableau everything seems to be setup correctly, however I can't seem to get any data back from Tableau on my website. Sadly I'm not getting any errors back either. I'm no backend expert, I know some basic PHP, so i'm probably overlooking something here. Any help would be apperciated!

It might be important to note that our website is SSL secure, I don't know how far this impacts this.

So this is what I'm loading after the user has succesfully logged into our system:

```
$server = "our server ip";
$view_url = "tableau view url";
$user = 'admin';

function get_trusted_url($user,$server,$view_url) {

  $params = ':embed=yes&:toolbar=yes';

  $ticket = get_trusted_ticket($server, $user, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

  if (strcmp($ticket, "-1") != 0) {

    return "http://$server/trusted/$ticket/$view_url?$params";

  }

  else 

    return 0;

}
```

:

```
function get_trusted_ticket($wgserver, $user, $remote_addr) {

  $params = array(

    'username' => $user,

    'client_ip' => $remote_addr

  );

  return do_post_request("https://$wgserver/trusted", $params);

}
```

:

```
function do_post_request($url, $data, $optional_headers = null)
{
  $params = array('http' => array(
              'method' => 'POST',
              'content' => http_build_query($data)
            ));
  if ($optional_headers !== null) {
    $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
  }
  $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
  $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
  if (!$fp) {
    throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
  if ($response === false) {
    throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  return $response;
}
```

And this is where I try to show the data:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://IP/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js"></script> 
<object class="tableauViz" width="1519" height="693" style="display:none;"> 
     <param name="path" value="<?php echo get_trusted_url($user,$server,$view_url)?>" /> 
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

Trusted Authentication involves requesting a ticket from Tableau Server and then redeeming that ticket. Troubleshooting any issues that are occurring therefore boils down to determining which part of that process is failing, and then fixing the problem.

As a first step, I would suggest running through the [Troubleshoot Trusted Authentication](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/help.htm#trusted_auth_trouble.htm) page.

That said, I noticed that your script used to show the data is pulling the `viz_v1.js` file over `http` and not `https`. Was that a typo?